# How to upload zip file and give permanent link to its contents in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am a fresher on Javascript and Node JS. I am looking for the solution to upload a zip file which contains pictures only and give these pictures permanent link. For now I can upload a zip file and extract all pictures in it as below:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var multer = require('multer');
var fs = require('fs');
var AdmZip = require('adm-zip');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'public/uploads/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
});
var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).any();



/* get home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'express' });
});

router.post('/', upload, function (req, res) {
    var zip = new AdmZip("./public/uploads/Camera Roll.zip");
    zip.extractAllTo('public/uploads/', true);
    res.send(req.files);   
});


module.exports = router;
```

Once I upload a zip file I saved it in 'public/uploads/'. How can I get the path which save uploaded zip file because now I just identify it in my code (var zip = new AdmZip("./public/uploads/Camera Roll.zip");). Is there any variable to denote it? And once I unzip the file all pictures are in the folder 'public/uploads', does that mean I gave a permanent link to all pictures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found. Just use req.file.path but need to use var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single(filename) firstly;